# Parse error in php

Tags: php, syntax-error

in my website all pages contain `Follow Us` panal so inspite or writing it on all pages I have created a seperate `modFollow.php` file and included it in all pages, I don't know whether its a correct way or not but I am gettein this error message-
my indexpage code -

```
<div class="follow">         
        <?php include 'modFollow.php'; ?>
    </div>
```

modFollow.php code-

```
<?php

//follow us module

echo "<h2 class='star'>Follow Us</h2>"
echo "<hr width='100%' color='WhiteSmoke' align='left'>"
echo "<a href='#'><img src='images/twitter.png' width = '35px' height = '32px' title =  'Twitter'/></a>"        
echo "<a href='#'><img src='images/facebook.png' width = '35px' height = '32px' title = 'FaceBook'/></a>"       
echo "<a href='#'><img src='images/rss.jpg' width = '35px' height = '32px' title = 'RSS'/></a>"         
echo "<a href='#'><img src='images/orkut.jpeg' width = '35px' height = '34px' title = 'Orkut'/></a>"  

?>
```

**ERROR: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\shizin\modFollow.php on line 6**

Comment: Why are you `echoing` pure HTML in the first place?

Comment: as other says missing ";" at the end of each statment in follow.php file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

oh....what a silly mistake I was forgetting **;** in modFolloe.php

Comment: please post as a comment;this is not an answer

Answer (score 2):

each of the echo lines needs to end with
    ;

Comment: I was shocked to see so many responses at once.. hah

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="follow">         
        <?php 
        include ('modFollow.php'); 
        ?>
    </div>
```

and dont forget to give `;` behind each echo statement

Comment: `include` is a language construct, you can use it without parenthesis without any problem. In fact, many developers prefer to do so.

Answer (score 0):

In php every statment must be terminated by semi colon [;].

you forget to add this at end of the statment.